Screenshot of the Week #119
This contest is over.
previous contest | next contest
Hello and welcome to the 119th edition of the Screenshot of the Week!
To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! Joachim's screenshot from tiny-glade won with 12 upvotes!


To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
Stack Exchange’s Code of Conduct still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.
How long will the contest run?
We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2024-07-08, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.
After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2024-07-15, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

No Theme
There is no theme this week.
As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a question of its own.  Additionally, there is the hall of fame you can check out that contains all the previous contest winners.



deus-ex-mankind-divided

I thought I saw Max Payne for some reasons

@Clockwork , > "No matter how long you spend climbing out, you can still fall back down in an instant." ~ Max Payne ( https://youtu.be/BfAIx6IwLvw )

"Mad Men" vibes here

Fight by night in kingdom-hearts-3 Sora vs yozora.


Two of my buddies are currently doing a critical playthrough on KH3, so I found this screenshot satisfying.

The Shot is a little bit dark .

@Wondercricket thanks for the missing s in my tag

Muck Factory - sim-city-3000


Ooh, you've pushed my nostalgia button with this one. :D

@DLosc Same, you can thank Steam, it's currently $3 AU

Oh overwatch-2, you're so punny...


This can be found in the newly released Runasapi map, based in Peru.
Peru is one of the South American countries that has lots of llamas.
Fun fact - Emperor Kuzco is also from Peru, and in the animated movies, he's transformed into a llama

"You threw off my groove" - Emperor Kuzco

terranigma


I heard this game was never released in the US and wasn't released on the Nintendo Switch (yet). If you can get a chance at playing it, I can wholeheartedly endorse it.

I have a snes Version.

.... you actually know that game and you choose a random indoor screen? ^_^' You could at least capture the underground towers top (which btw have one of the best 30 sec loop tune in the entire SNES library)

@Ꮢedacted To be fair, this is a very old screenshot and it's when you barely woke up at the beginning of the game. Just looking at it, I can hear Crysta theme and it reminds me how much this game changed me. But yeah, that tune and that area you mentioned, it truly was something.

Anyway, at least this had a Pal release. Some great games weren't that lucky, I think I am probably the only one who know who Josette even is in my city.... We could be re-releasing those old gems... but nooo, let's port FF7 to smartwatches next instead


a little taste of what Patrick Hyarms could be expecting if he keeps trying to date Rean's sister Elise in trails-of-cold-steel-iv

I Made the Same Shot today. Bonding Event with altina near ymir
